# Copy,Cut and past qlineEdit

Tags: c++, qt5.4

I'm using different `QLineEdit` edit boxed in my application.
Now I will enable copy, cut and past function on the text inside the `QLineEdit`.

When I connect the three shortcuts of the functions to the public slots of the `QLineEdit` then only the past function will work. The copy and cut does not work.

Also when I check the `contextmenu` when right click the selected text and press copy it doesn't work. Does someone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
QShortcut pasteShortcut(QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+V")), ui.lineEdit);
QShortcut cutShortcut(QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+X")), ui.lineEdit);
QShortcut copyShortcut(QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+C")), ui.lineEdit);

connect(&copyShortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), ui.lineEdit, SLOT(ui.lineEdit->copy()));
connect(&cutShortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), ui.lineEdit, SLOT(ui.lineEdit->cut()));
connect(&pasteShortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), ui.lineEdit, SLOT(ui.lineEdit->paste()));
```

Comment: Copy/paste should work automatically for QLineEdits without any of these.

Comment: It doens't. I'm using Qt5.4 (X64) with Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: Can you try connecting the shortcuts to debug functions where you just print some random text to see whether the problem lies with the shortcuts not being activated or really with the `copy()` and `cut()` methods themselves?

Comment: Just tested it and the slot was not called after sending the signal. So the shortcut is not being activated.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like wrong format for `SLOT` macro. This should be correct:

```
connect(&copyShortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), ui.lineEdit, SLOT(copy()));
connect(&cutShortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), ui.lineEdit, SLOT(cut()));
connect(&pasteShortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), ui.lineEdit, SLOT(paste()));
```

In general, always use Qt Creator's autocompletion, when using `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros, because getting it wrong will not produce build error, but runtime error (because the macro arguments are handled as a string and resolved at runtime). Better yet, use [the "new" Qt5 style connect syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), which doesn't use macros and can produce build error if you get it wrong. Example:

```
connect(&copyShortcut, &QShortCut::activated, ui.lineEdit, &QLineEdit::copy);
```

---

Also, make sure that lifetime of those `QShortcut` objects is long enough, but not too long...

Long enough means, they should not be local variables in a method, because then they will be destroyed when the method returns (this might be ok if you use a modal dialog, and want the shortcuts to only exist while the dialog is open).

Too long means, if they haven't been destroyed by the time `ui.lineEdit` is destructed, then `ui.lineEdit` destruction will try to `delete` them, because you set their parent. This obviously will not work since they have not been allocated with `new`, you will most likely get a crash due to Undefined Behavior.

If unsure, change them into pointers and use `new` and let `ui.lineEdit` to clean them up when done.